# Android stalkerware abilities

Tags: root-access, security, rom-flashing, factory-reset, malware

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 4 (4X). I just unlocked the bootloader and cleaned all flashed my phone because the stalkerware my friend installed wasn't going away by a factory reset.

After some days from flashing, I found out that there were started appearing some files in my file explorer app like random APKs and files. Here are some pictures:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: https://ibb.co/WsH7g0M] | [image: https://ibb.co/4RhKBmm] | [image: https://ibb.co/Bnh4zWG] | [image: https://ibb.co/5rrZxFw] |
| [image: https://ibb.co/P1fY2JQ] | [image: https://ibb.co/QkpVfcD] | [image: https://ibb.co/8mQQVD6] |  |

I did basic googling and they seem like system apps, but this is my first time seeing them. I tried to delete it manually by pressing delete, but it cannot be deleted. Antiviruses don't seem to find it.

Does anyone know why these came up? Could it be due to stalkerware? What's the next course of action if a reflash and factory reset don't remove stalkerware other than getting a new phone?

Comment: System partition is usually read-only and usually protected by Android Verified Boot, so any unauthorized modification should be detected by Android. So it is more likely Xiaomi had put them there, may be they already existed before you recognized them or a system update placed them there.

Comment: @Robert XDA says it is not stock ROM but from Huawei ? Any idea about this? Is it possible for stalkerware to do this?

Comment: What is your build number? Go to **Settings** > **About Phone** and then scroll down to the **Build Number** at the bottom.

Comment: @mchid


Serial number-9393f1cc7d44

Comment: I'm not finding anything for that. How did you determine that it's from Huawei?

Comment: Also, Huawei usually has (or used to have) a fairly unique interface for the OS instead of what you would normally see for Android, even on the Android based version.

Comment: @mchid One of the devs over at XDA told fido uaf client is Huawei and not stock
Can you link(resources )me the bestf method of detecting and removing stalkerware on Android thanks for the reply

Comment: it doesn't matter, these aren't system apps but just some random downloaded files. if you did not download it. identify the culprit app and uninstall. if you want have full security, roll back to stock ROM and lock bootloader

Comment: @alecxs that's exactly what I did and then this happened there I did a factory reset plus a full reflash I couldn't find any culprit app

Comment: then most likely you restored the suspicious app from google drive backup. use [official](https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/santoni) ROM and create new google account

Comment: I had downloaded the same fastboot rom and also created a new Google account with 2fa(app) and password manager but I don't think I signed out of Google before proceeding to flash but I checked thde drive thers nothing In there is this necessary or will the flash remove it

Comment: @alecxs either this or pc is infected right

Comment: Does anyone know the best way to detect stalkerware on android?

Comment: Idk but I know if you flash stock ROM it's gone for sure